# How to encode a Hex string to Integer in BCB XE

Tags: c++, hex, c++builder, c++builder-xe

I want to convert a hex string to a 16 bit Decimal in RAD Studio C++ Builder XE.

For example, I have the hex string "8FC". The Binary representation of this is 100011111100. The Decimal representation of this is: 2300.

How to do this conversion in C++ Builder XE?

Comment: Look at [`istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) and [`hex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex). The example on [`hex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) does exactly what you want.

Comment: Whether it can be used in C++ Builder XE? The `std::hex` in `C++ Builder XE` is ask the `ios_base & _Iosbase` as the parameters. Please notice that I use `C++ Builder XE`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Create an [sscce](http://sscce.org), i.e. the smallest possible example which should work but doesn't, which we can all try at home. Or try the [example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) I linked and see whether you can make it work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, I find the correct way how to do this conversion on [**this article**](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=568001#568001). It just try to call the [**`StrToInt()`**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.SysUtils.StrToInt) procedure but prepend a "**$**" like this:

```
s1 = "8FC";
int i = StrToInt(UnicodeString("$") + s1);
Edit1->Text = IntToStr(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to use [`std:stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream)

```
#include <ios>
#include <sstream>
#include <ostream>
#include <iostream> // MS & Borland seem to be deficient in requiring this

int main()
{
    unsigned short val;

    std::stringstream st("8FC");
    st >> std::hex >> val;

    // convert it back to text as decimal
    st.clear();
    st << std::dec << val;
    std::cout << "Decimal value " << st.str() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Whether it can be used in C++ Builder XE? The `std::hex` in C++ Builder XE is ask the `ios_base & _Iosbase` parameters.
Please notice that I use C++ Builder XE. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `std::hex` is part of the C++ Standard Library. I've updated my answer to include the additional required header and conversion back to text as decimal

Comment: I've try your suggest but it still raising any error message. This is the messages: `[BCC32 Error] uPort.cpp(133): E2285 Could not find a match for 'std::stringstream::basic_stringstream(UnicodeString)'`, `[BCC32 Error] uPort.cpp(133): E2031 Cannot cast from 'UnicodeString' to 'std::stringstream'`

Comment: Your compiler settings must be configured to interpret multibyte strings as unicode. Use `std::wstringstream` instead or change your settings.

Comment: How to change that settings? I have open my compiler settings but I can't find the interpret multibyte section. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `std::wstringstream` until you have a chance to Google it.